# capture Beacon frames using Linux c sockets

Tags: sockets, beacon

I would like to capture Beacon frames from my router by using Linux c sockets.

1. What are the socket opening definitions? 
   Are those appropriate?
   sock_raw = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))
2. Should it be under management or Monitor mode?

Thanks a lot

Tali
p.s I don’t want to implement this using third party libraries, such as libpcap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to my knowledge:

1) Yes. You are correct in declaring `int sock_raw = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));`

2) Your device needs to be in Monitor Mode to capture beacon frames. If your linux machine has the `aircrack-ng` suite installed, you can use `airmon-ng start [DEV NAME]` to put it into monitor mode or if net-tools are installed etc, you can do the following (example uses 'wlan0' as device i want to put into monitor mode):

```
ifconfig wlan0 down 
iw wlan0 set type monitor 
ip link set wlan0 name wlan0mon && ifconfig wlan0mon up
```

Next, if you want to continue using your monitor mode socket in C, you can use the following:

```c
struct ifreq ifr;
struct sockaddr_ll ll;
assert(sizeof(ifr.ifr_name) == IFNAMSIZ);

int sock_raw = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "wlan0mon", sizeof(ifr._ifr_name)); 
ioctl(sock_raw, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);

ll.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
ll.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
ll.sll_family = PF_PACKET;

bind(sock_raw, (struct sockaddr *)&ll, sizeof(ll));
```

This C code sets the raw socket up for monitor mode use then binds it to the monitor mode device. Now it is able to be used to send/recv 802.11 frames etc. I hope this helps :)